# Kubernetes equivalent for docker compose configuration of logging ( fluentd )

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging, docker-compose, fluentd

I am using hybrid approach where in for few services I am using simple docker compose approach and for others I am using kubernetes for deployment. For both approaches I want to keep my centralized logging same ( fluentd ).
Here is my docker compose file ,

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  inventory:
    image: SOME_SERVICE
    container_name: SOME_SERVICE
    network_mode: "host"
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    mem_limit: 2000m
    oom_kill_disable: true
    logging: &logging <<-- This Part
      driver: fluentd
      options:
       fluentd-address: IP:PORT
       tag: "server.{{.Name}}"
```

I want convert this logging part to the equivalent kubernetes configuration. How can I do this ?

Comment: Please let us know whether your problem has been resolved by the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no options to control logging in a [Pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/).  Instead, you need a cluster-wide log collector.  [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the Kubernetes documentation describes the setup.  As a programmer this isn't something you control, you'll have to ask your cluster administrator or your local DevOps team to configure it for you.